# Chamar procedimento no OnClick da <area> no Image Map em ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html5, asp.net, vb.net

Boa tarde,
tenho este código:

```
<img src="../Image/sala.png" USEMAP="#sala" BORDER=0>
```

```
<area name="window" shape="poly" coords="633,82,631,117,627,145,625,160,644,162,671" href=""  alt="window" title="" OnMouseOver="window.status='window'; return true" OnMouseOut="window.status=''; return true">
```

Tenho uma sub no vb que chama uma caixa de diálogo que queria que fosse chamada no onclick do código acima. Alguem me pode ajudar? Obrigado :)